# Retrofit2 parameters in Fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I can make calls without a hitch as long as there are no parameters. I know that as a beginner to app programming that this will be a ridiculously simple thing I missed or something overly complex, but here goes.

I have an interface inside a fragment and have the @Query in place like so:

```
interface RewardsApiService {
    @GET("JSON/return-data.asp")
    fun getCID(
        @Query("cid") strCustomerID: String,
        @Query("process") strProcess: String
    )
    fun getRewards(): retrofit2.Call<ResponseData<List<RewardsCards>>>
}
```

My question is this: Where do I define and assign those variables, strCustomerID and strProcess, so the interface can use them? strCustomerID is a SharedPreference.

Comment: After a little more plugging away with it, I found out where I believe I should put the getCID function, which is in my createService() function. The editor throws no errors and every reference is found. However when I hit the @Query line, the app closes. Any thoughts?

``code``
rewardsApiService?.getCID("168","getrewardsavailable")
``code``

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You don't. Retrofit autogenerates the code based on what you have tagged with `@GET`, `@Query`, etc.

You should call it like this:

`val call = service.getCID("foo", "bar")`

However the generated call will url will look like this:
`[your base url]/JSON/return-data.asp?cid=foo?process=bar`
So make sure that url matches what you want.

---

Outside of the retrofit specific stuff there are some deeper architectural concerns. I'd have a look at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide and consider restructuring the project slightly.

For example, you dont want to be making API calls from within a fragment. This creates concerns around potentially doing IO on the main or UI thread and you are likely to end up trying to figure out crashes around that.

At a bare minimum I'd recommend splitting the interface out into a separate file and making sure your network call is done within a coroutine with IO scope.

Comment: while i agree with the second half of your answer, i think it _might_ be outside the scope of what OP is looking for, at least at the moment, but i suppose it doesn't do any harm with leaving it there :)

Comment: 100% agree that it's outside the scope, he did say he is a beginner so just providing some guidance :)

Comment: I understand it was outside of the scope and it was advice. After a little more plugging away with it, I found out where I believe I should put the getCID function. The editor throws no errors and every reference is found. However when I hit the @Query line, the app closes.